# .htaccess RewriteRule file in another folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a two-part site, the first part on the home page, I have one .htaccess file and I use these htaccess commands to rewrite their files

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap-([0-9]+).xml$ sitemap-xml.php?page=$1
```

The other part of the site is on folder called bio, and i use these htaccess commands to rewrite their files

```
RewriteRule ^/bio/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /bio/show_person.php?id=$1&url=$2  [QSA,L]
```

but the bio RewriteRule dose not work, how can i fix it

here is my complete htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bio/


RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ show_person.php?id=$1&url=$2  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^job-([0-9]+)/$ show_job.php?id=$1  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^nationality-([0-9]+)/$ show_nationality.php?id=$1  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^borg-([0-9]+)/$ show_borg.php?borg=$1  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^birth-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/$ show_birthday.php?day=$1&month=$2  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^birthyear-([0-9]+)/$ show_birthyear.php?year=$1  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^death-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/$ show_deathday.php?day=$1&month=$2  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^deathyear-([0-9]+)/$ show_deathyear.php?year=$1  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^job-([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ show_job.php?id=$1&page=$2  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^nationality-([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ show_nationality.php?id=$1&page=$2  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^borg-([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ show_borg.php?borg=$1&page=$2  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^birth-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ show_birthday.php?day=$1&month=$2&page=$3  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^birthyear-([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ show_birthyear.php?year=$1&page=$2  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^death-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ show_deathday.php?day=$1&month=$2&page=$3  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^deathyear-([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ show_deathyear.php?year=$1&page=$2  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap-([0-9]+).xml$ sitemap.php?page=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this rule in `bio/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bio/

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(.*)$ show_person.php?id=$1&url=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Provide complete details. What URL did you try and what error did you get? If `bio/.htaccess` has other code then post it in question.

Comment: this is the url https://www.orared.com/bio/4/%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%8A/

Comment: There is probably inside the code that is making a `R=302` redirect from `https://www.orared.com/bio/show_person.php?id=4` to `https://www.orared.com/bio/4/%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%8A/` thus causing redirect loop.

Comment: it works on my localhost server but on the site server dosn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192228/discussion-between-anubhava-and-mahmoud-samy).

Comment: i think you were right there was a code problem and i fix it thanks for helping